# All textboxes disabled after popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

This problem only occurs on IE8 (not IE8 compatibility mode).
I have a file called sample.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
    <script src='http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body style='position:relative;z-index:1'>
<input><a href="javascript:Popup('test1.html');">Click</a>
<script>
function Popup(url) {
    overlay = $("<div style='position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:10005'><div style='position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:black; -ms-filter:\"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)\"; filter: alpha(opacity=50);'></div>");
    iframe = $("<iframe name='Overlay' style='position:absolute; height:80%; width:80%; top:10%; left:10%;' src='" + url + "'></iframe>");
    closebut = $("<img style='position:absolute; cursor:pointer; right:10%; top:10%;' width='24px' height='24px' src='/images/close.png' onclick='RemovePopup()' >");
    overlay.append(iframe).append(closebut);
    $('body').prepend(overlay);
}
function RemovePopup() {
    overlay.animate({top:'100%'},800,'swing', function() { $(this).remove(); });
}
</script>
</div></body></html>
```

Here is the complete content of test1.html: `<html><head></head><body><input></body></html>`

So create these 2 files, open sample.htm in IE8, click the link to open the popup, type something in the textbox there, close the popup, try and type in the first textbox. If you can, repeat 2 or 3 times.
Eventually the first textbox becomes disabled.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If people don't want to create these 2 files, please till me and I'll try and put them online somewhere.

Comment: No problem recreating it. Possibly something to do with the opacity filter but I'm still looking at it.

Comment: It seems that clicking on the `iframe` while it's closing (after clicking the close button) causes this to happen.

Comment: Clicking on it anytime causes it (even before closing)

Comment: Weird bug, happens randomly for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially I think this is a `focus` problem. If you can get the browser into the situation where the `<input>` *seems* disabled then you can actually <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the `<input>` and enter a value as expected.

I believe the `$(this).remove();` call to remove the iframe at the end of the animation is causing the problem when an element in the iframe has focus. I'd suggest giving the first `<input>` focus before removing the iframe.

For example, use `$('input:first').focus();` if it is the first input. It seems to work in my testing here.

Comment: Much appreciated. I used jQuery('input:text:visible:first').focus() to cover all cases.

Comment: This is a really annoying bug since it seems to only effect IE8 for certain versions or on certain machines.